# TikZ: How to define the level spacing between node children?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, forest

In this MWE, is there anyway to automatically set the spacing between the second parent children instead of this manual approach

```
first/.style={level distance=6ex},
second/.style={level distance=12ex},
third/.style={level distance=18ex},
```

?

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning,calc,trees}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\def\gap{10mm}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
        node distance = 18mm and \textwidth/3,
        on grid,
        font = \sffamily,
        line/.style = {draw, -Latex,black},
        rbox/.style = {draw=blue!80!black, fill=blue!20,
            rounded corners, inner sep=2mm,
            text width=(\textwidth-6*\gap)/3, align=center},
        grandchild/.style={grow=down,xshift=+2em,anchor=west,edge from parent path={ [line] ([xshift=0,yshift=0em]\tikzparentnode.south) |- (\tikzchildnode.west)}},
        first/.style={level distance=6ex},
        second/.style={level distance=12ex},
        third/.style={level distance=18ex},
    ]

    \node (Grandparent)   [rbox] {Grandparent};

    \node (1stparent)  [rbox,below  left=of Grandparent] {1st parent};

    \node (2ndparent)  [rbox,below=of Grandparent]{2nd parent}
    child[grandchild,first] {node[rbox]{1st child}}
    child[grandchild,second] {node[rbox]{2nd child}}
    child[grandchild,third] {node[rbox]{3rd child}};

    \node (3rdparent)  [rbox,below right=of Grandparent] {3rd parent};

    \path [line] (Grandparent) -- coordinate (a) (2ndparent);
    \path [line] (a) -| (1stparent);
    \path [line] (a) -| (3rdparent);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

### Edit

Following cfr [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/336136/2288) forest approach, how can I edit this code to make the children at level 3 (e.g. He-Ne, I, CO2, etc) be folder-like?

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,shadows.blur}
\begin{document}
\newlength\gap
\setlength\gap{10mm}
\begin{forest}
    forked edges,
    for tree={
        draw=blue!80!darkgray,
        fill=blue!80!darkgray!25,
        rounded corners,
        text width=(\textwidth-6*\gap)/3,
        edge={-Latex},
        font=\sffamily,
        text centered,
        blur shadow,
    },
    %  where level=0{%
    parent anchor=children,
    %  }{%
    if level=2{%
        folder,
        grow'=0,
        l sep+=10pt,
        before typesetting nodes={child anchor=north},
        edge path'={%
            (!u.parent anchor) -- ++(0,-10pt) -| (.child anchor)
        },
        }{},
    %  }
    [Active Media
        [Gases
            [Atoms
                [He-Ne]
                [I]
            ]
            [Molecules
                [CO2]
                [CO]
            ]
            [Ions
                [Ar]
                [Kr]
            ]
            [Excimers
                [ArF]
            ]
        ]
        [Liquids
            [Dyes
                [Rhodamines]
            ]
        ]
        [Solids
            [Insulators
                [Nd:YAG]
            ]
            [Semiconductors
                [GaAs]
            ]
        ]
    ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't get the same output as you. Some lines are missing.

Comment: @cfr I fixed it.

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/307691/how-to-combine-these-tree-diagrams-in-tikz, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/300373/saving-horizontal-space-in-tree-diagram, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/299170/saving-vertical-space-in-tree-diagram.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are happy to use Forest, the package will layout the tree automatically for you. The `folder` option from the `edges` library makes this much easier with Forest version 2 than version 1. However, there is a slight glitch in that it is not possible to combine `folder` with `forked edges` easily. So, for the first edges, we set the `edge path` manually and override `child anchor`.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,shadows.blur}
\begin{document}
\newlength\gap
\setlength\gap{10mm}
\begin{forest}
  forked edges,
  for tree={
    draw=blue!80!darkgray,
    fill=blue!80!darkgray!25,
    rounded corners,
    text width=(\textwidth-6*\gap)/3,
    edge={-Latex},
    font=\sffamily,
    text centered,
    blur shadow,
  },
  where level=0{%
    parent anchor=children,
  }{%
    folder,
    grow'=0,
    l sep+=10pt,
    if level=1{%
      before typesetting nodes={child anchor=north},
      edge path'={%
        (!u.parent anchor) -- ++(0,-10pt) -| (.child anchor)
      },
    }{},
  }
  [Grandparent
    [1\textsuperscript{st} parent
    ]
    [2\textsuperscript{nd} parent
      [1\textsuperscript{st} child]
      [2\textsuperscript{nd} child]
      [3\textsuperscript{rd} child]
    ]
    [3\textsuperscript{rd} parent
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: Forest family]

## EDIT

For the tree added in the edited question, you might adjust the code as follows.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,shadows.blur}
\begin{document}
\newlength\gap
\setlength\gap{10mm}
\begin{forest}
  forked edges,
  for tree={
    draw=blue!80!darkgray,
    fill=blue!80!darkgray!25,
    rounded corners,
    minimum width=(\textwidth-6*\gap)/3,
    minimum height=4ex,
    edge={-Latex},
    font=\sffamily,
    text centered,
    blur shadow,
  },
  where={level()<=1}{%
    parent anchor=children,
   }{%
     folder,
     grow'=0,
     l sep+=5pt,
     if level=2{%
       before typesetting nodes={child anchor=north},
       !u.s sep'+=10pt,
       edge path'={%
         (!u.parent anchor) -- ++(0,-10pt) -| (.child anchor)
       },
     }{},
   }
    [Active Media
        [Gases
            [Atoms
                [He-Ne]
                [I]
            ]
            [Molecules
                [CO2]
                [CO]
            ]
            [Ions
                [Ar]
                [Kr]
            ]
            [Excimers
                [ArF]
            ]
        ]
        [Liquids
            [Dyes
                [Rhodamines]
            ]
        ]
        [Solids
            [Insulators
                [Nd:YAG]
            ]
            [Semiconductors
                [GaAs]
            ]
        ]
    ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Note that the key level here is the one before the one where siblings are stacked vertically. If that is level 3, the crucial level is level 2. Everything before that level gets styled in one way, everything after gets styled another. Nodes at that level need some tweaking.

If you say

```
if level=2 ...
```

in the tree's preamble, it will have no effect as it is only applied to the root node, where the conditional fails. Likewise, options put here simpliciter only apply to the root. This is the difference between `if` and `where`: `where` issues `for tree`; `if` does not. See the manual for details and further options.

[image: example with later change of direction and switch to directory-style]

Comment: When I tried to extend your answer, I failed to get the folder-like level as desired. I would be grateful if you could take a look at my question edit.

Comment: @DiaaAbidou Please see edit above. You should probably take a look at the manual if you have not yet done so e.g. the difference between `if` and `where` is important and so is the use of `for tree` etc.

Comment: Many thanks for your clarification. I would be thankful if you could help me with another issue I couldn't figure out in [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/336427/2288).