# TikZ/Forest: How to uniquely color parent/children/grandchildren branch nodes?

Tags: forest

Following my [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/336115/2288), in this MWE, how to, for example, set a unique color for each parent/children/grandchildren branch in such a way that the color is gradually fainting or brightening while going downwards?

In other words, if I want to set blue color for the nodes `Parent 1`, `Child 1` and `Grandchild 1`, I would like make their fill colors be `blue!80`, `blue!50` and `blue!20`, respectively. Similarly, I would to set other colors for the other branches, and the respective nodes should be colored in the same way.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,shadows.blur}
\begin{document}
\newlength\gap
\setlength\gap{10mm}
\begin{forest}
  forked edges,
  for tree={
    draw=blue!80!darkgray,
    fill=blue!80!darkgray!25,
    rounded corners,
    minimum width=(\textwidth-6*\gap)/3,
    minimum height=4ex,
    edge={-Latex},
    font=\sffamily,
    text centered,
    blur shadow,
  },
  where={level()<=1}{%
    parent anchor=children,
    l sep+=10pt,
    s sep'+=10pt,
   }{%
     folder,
     grow'=0,
     l sep+=0pt,% length of edge to grand child
     if level=2{%
       before typesetting nodes={child anchor=north},
       !u.s sep'+=10pt,
       edge path'={%
         (!u.parent anchor) -- ++(0,-10pt) -| (.child anchor)
       },
     }{},
   }
    [Grandparent
        [Parent 1
            [Child 1
                [Grandchild 1]
            ]
        ]
        [Parent 2
            [Child 2
                [Grandchild 2]
            ]
        ]
        [Parent 3
            [Child 3
                [Grandchild 3]
            ]
        ]
    ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Haven't you asked this question before? :) [TikZ/Forest: How to format/stylize a node based on its level?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/327014/2693). The technique outlined in great detail there works here too I think.

Comment: I am not sure, but in my other question, the stylization is based on the level globally across all the branches. However, here in addition to level-based stylization, I need every branch (parent/children/grandchildren) to be uniquely colored.

Comment: Ok, then I misunderstood the question. The principle will be the same, but you may need to use a node walk, I think.

Comment: The forest or tikz manual is not friendly at least for me, but I will try to give them a look again.

Comment: It's a pretty daunting manual for sure. But we have @cfr to interpret it. :)

Comment: What colour should the root be?

Comment: @AlanMunn ??!!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a different version (slightly less complicated):

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,shadows.blur}
\begin{document}
\newlength\gap
\setlength\gap{10mm}
\forestset{parent color/.style args={#1}{
    {fill=#1},
    for tree={fill/.wrap pgfmath arg={#1!##1}{1/level()*80},draw=#1!80!darkgray}},
    root color/.style args={#1}{fill={{#1!60!gray!25},draw=#1!80!darkgray}}
}
\begin{forest}
  forked edges,
  for tree={%
    rounded corners,
    minimum width=(\textwidth-6*\gap)/3,
    minimum height=4ex,
    edge={-Latex},
    font=\sffamily,
    text centered,
    blur shadow,
  },
  where={level()<=1}{%
    parent anchor=children,
    l sep+=10pt,
    s sep'+=10pt,
   }{%
     folder,
     grow'=0,
     l sep+=2pt,% length of edge to grand child
     if level=2{%
       before typesetting nodes={child anchor=north},
       !u.s sep'+=10pt,
       edge path'={%
         (!u.parent anchor) -- ++(0,-10pt) -| (.child anchor)
       },
     }{},
   },
      [Grandparent,root color={brown}
        [Parent 1, parent color={red}
            [Child 1
                [Grandchild 1]
            ]
        ]
        [Parent 2,parent color={green}
            [Child 2
                [Grandchild 2]
            ]
        ]
        [Parent 3,parent color={yellow}
            [Child 3
                [Grandchild 3]
            ]
        ]
    ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For alignment with children, I don't understand why the parents are aligned with children left instead of center. I would be grateful, if you could help me with this issue in [my question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/336516/2288).

Answer (score 8):

You might use the following style `branch shade=from <colour> to <colour>` to shade the branches as follows.

[Edited to support colours such as `blue!80` which leave the specification of `white` as the second colour implicit`.]

The new version of the code also creates a `family tree` style for trees which should follow this structural pattern. `twist=<integer>` sets the level at which the change should take place, so that children in later levels will be set `folder` style i.e. directory-like. The default is `2`.

As Alan Munn indicated, this is really the same as before (which also implicitly relied on a nodewalk via, for example, the `.max` handler).

Note that

```
l sep+=0pt,
```

has no effect on anything whatsoever. It adds a length of zero to a dimension, which is obviously equivalent to nothing at all.

Then we can write

```
\begin{forest}
  family tree,
   [Grandparent, left color=cyan, right color=SpringGreen, middle color=Pink, draw=Silver
     [Parent 1, branch shade=from cyan to blue
       [Child 1
         [Grandchild 1]
       ]
     ]
     [Parent 2, branch shade=from Pink to WildStrawberry
       [Child 2
         [Grandchild 2]
       ]
     ]
     [Parent 3, branch shade=from SpringGreen to ForestGreen
       [Child 3
         [Grandchild 3]
       ]
     ]
   ]
\end{forest}
```

to produce the tree created by the version of the code in the original version of this answer.

[image: fancy-coloured tree]

As you can see, I had no idea what to do with the root.

Or we can write

```
\begin{forest}
  family tree,
   [Grandparent, fill=darkgray, text=Silver, double=Silver, draw=darkgray
     [Parent 1, branch shade=from blue!80 to blue!20
       [Child 1
         [Grandchild 1]
       ]
     ]
     [Parent 2, branch shade=from WildStrawberry!80 to WildStrawberry!20
       [Child 2
         [Grandchild 2]
       ]
     ]
     [Parent 3, branch shade=from ForestGreen!80 to ForestGreen!20
       [Child 3
         [Grandchild 3]
       ]
     ]
   ]
\end{forest}
```

to make use of `white` implicitly and style the root node differently.

[image: implicit use of white & plainer root]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz,dvipsnames,svgnames,rgb]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,shadows.blur}
\forestset{
  declare dimen register=gap,
  gap'=10mm,
  declare count register=twist,
  twist'=2,
  family tree/.style={
    forked edges,
    for tree={
      rounded corners,
      minimum width/.wrap pgfmath arg={##1}{(\textwidth-6*(gap))/3},
      minimum height=4ex,
      edge={-Latex},
      font=\sffamily,
      text centered,
      blur shadow,
      edge=thick,
    },
    where={level()<(twist)}{%
      parent anchor=children,
      l sep+=10pt,
      s sep'+=10pt,
    }{%
      folder,
      grow'=0,
      l sep'+=2pt,
      if={level()==(twist)}{%
        before typesetting nodes={child anchor=north},
        !u.s sep'+=10pt,
        edge path'={%
          (!u.parent anchor) -- ++(0,-10pt) -| (.child anchor)
        },
      }{},
    },
  },
  branch shade/.style args={from #1 to #2}{
    before typesetting nodes={
      tempcountc/.max={level}{current,tree},
      tempcountb/.option=level,
      tempcounta=(tempcountc)-(tempcountb)+1,
      temptoksa/.option=name,
      TeX/.wrap pgfmath arg={
        \colorlet{##1col1}{#1}
        \colorlet{##1col2}{#2}
      }{name()},
      for tree={
        rounded corners,
        top color/.wrap 2 pgfmath args={##2col2!##1!##2col1}{100*((level()-(tempcountb))/(tempcounta))}{(temptoksa)},
        +edge/.wrap 2 pgfmath args={##2col2!##1!##2col1}{100*((level()-(tempcountb))/(tempcounta))}{(temptoksa)},
        bottom color/.wrap 2 pgfmath args={##2col2!##1!##2col1}{100*((level()-(tempcountb)+1)/(tempcounta))}{(temptoksa)},
        draw/.wrap 2 pgfmath args={##2col2!##1!##2col1}{100*((level()-(tempcountb)+1)/(tempcounta))}{(temptoksa)},
        thick,
      },
    }
  },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  family tree,
   [Grandparent, left color=cyan, right color=SpringGreen, middle color=Pink, draw=Silver
     [Parent 1, branch shade=from cyan to blue
       [Child 1
         [Grandchild 1]
       ]
     ]
     [Parent 2, branch shade=from Pink to WildStrawberry
       [Child 2
         [Grandchild 2]
       ]
     ]
     [Parent 3, branch shade=from SpringGreen to ForestGreen
       [Child 3
         [Grandchild 3]
       ]
     ]
   ]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
  family tree,
   [Grandparent, fill=darkgray, text=Silver, double=Silver, draw=darkgray
     [Parent 1, branch shade=from blue!80 to blue!20
       [Child 1
         [Grandchild 1]
       ]
     ]
     [Parent 2, branch shade=from WildStrawberry!80 to WildStrawberry!20
       [Child 2
         [Grandchild 2]
       ]
     ]
     [Parent 3, branch shade=from ForestGreen!80 to ForestGreen!20
       [Child 3
         [Grandchild 3]
       ]
     ]
   ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your decent answer. If you don't mind, I would like to get your explanations about some stuff: 1- when I tried to make `branch shade = from blue!80 to blue!20`, I got an error. is there any missing package to be loaded? 2- For the `Grandparent` node, I tried to make it uniformly filled with one color by replacing `left color=cyan, right color=SpringGreen, middle color=Pink` with `color=white`, but the result was not what I wanted.

Comment: @DiaaAbidou Maybe you want `fill=white` for the grandparent? `color=white` will affect the colour of the text, border and fill. If you want the node drawn in white also, use `fill=white, draw=white`. For the branch colouring, try `branch shade=from blue!80!white to blue!20white` or you could change the style definition to take only one colour. I did it this way because it is a bit more flexible if it allows 2 colours. What's happening is you are getting `blue!80!<number>!blue!20` which won't work. Actually, let me do something else. Hang on.

Comment: @DiaaAbidou Please see edited answer above.