# How to format a taxonomy tree from forest library

Tags: tikz-pgf, forest

I have used [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/336619/226253) awesome reply by the user cfr to edit and come up with a nice tree that I can use. However there are some small things that I wanted to change. I played with some numbers but the code for it is a little bit over my head. I couldn't make any other changes after what I have done and shown below. I feel like I am missing something but I can't figure it out.

I am trying to replicate a tree from another book but my trees don't look quite the same. I would like the first split to also be straight and I want the leaf nodes (sometimes also non-leaf nodes) to not have a box around them. I am using the book Smart Card Handbook 3rd edition by W.Rankl and W. Effing. The trees I am trying to replicate are the ones on pages 18 and 255. Here is what I currently have:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\forestset{
  declare dimen register=gap,
  gap'=10mm,
  declare count register=twist,
  twist'=1,
  family tree too/.style={
    draw,
    forked edges,
    for tree={
      fill=gray!0,
      rounded corners=1pt,
      minimum width/.wrap pgfmath arg={##1}{(\textwidth-6*(gap))/3},
      minimum height=4ex,
      font=\sffamily,
      text centered,
      edge=thick,
    },
    where={level()<(twist)}{%
      parent anchor=children,
      l sep+=5pt,
    }{%
      draw,
      folder,
      grow'=0,
      if={level()==(twist)}{%
        before typesetting nodes={child anchor=north},
        anchor=north,
        edge path'={%
          (!u.parent anchor) -- (.child anchor)
        },
      }{
        l sep'+=2pt,
        if level=2{
          before computing xy={
            l/.wrap pgfmath arg={##1}{14pt-((\textwidth-6*(gap))/6)}
          },
        }{}
      },
    },
  },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!ht]
    \centering
    \begin{forest}
        family tree too,
        [Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet con
                [Lorem ips
                            [Lorem ipsum
                                    [Lorem ipsum dolor sit.]
                                    [Lorem ipsum dolor s]
                            ]
                            [Lorem ipsum dolor si
                                    [Lorem ipsum dolor s]
                                    [Lorem ipsum dolo]
                            ]
                    ]
                    [Lorem ipsum dolor sit am
                            [Lorem ipsum d]
                            [Lorem ipsum]
                            [Lorem ipsum]
                    ]
            ]
    \end{forest}
    \caption{A small tree}
    \label{fig:smart_card_types}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

and here is how it looks:

[image: The look of the taxonomy tree that I have]

And here is what I am trying to replicate:

[image: The first tree that I am trying to replicate] Taken from (1) p. 18

[image: The second tree that I am trying to replicate] Taken from (1) p. 255

(1): Wolfgang Rankl and Wolfgang Effing, Smart card handbook, 3rd ed. Chichester, West Sussex, England ; Hoboken, NJ, USA: J. Wiley, 2003.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a somewhat simplified version of your code that (I think) does what you want.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!ht]
    \centering
    \begin{forest}
        forked edges, folder indent=1cm,
        where={level()<1}{}{folder, grow'=east},
        where={level()>0}{l sep+=1cm}{},
        for tree={
            fork sep=4mm,
            thick, edge=thick,
            font=\sffamily,
            if n children=0{if n=1{yshift=-5mm}{}, for parent={s sep=0mm}}{draw, minimum height=4ex, minimum width=4cm}
        }
        [Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet con, calign=edge midpoint, s sep=2cm, font=\bfseries\sffamily
            [Lorem ips
                [Lorem ipsum
                    [Lorem ipsum dolor sit.]
                    [Lorem ipsum dolor s]
                ]
                [Lorem ipsum dolor si
                    [Lorem ipsum dolor s]
                    [Lorem ipsum dolo]
                ]
            ]
            [Lorem ipsum dolor sit am
                [Lorem ipsum d]
                [Lorem ipsum]
                [Lorem ipsum]
            ]
        ]
    \end{forest}
    \caption{A small tree}
    \label{fig:smart_card_types}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```